# How to run Swiftlint for selected files?

Tags: swift, swiftlint

I am looking for the way to run Swiftlint selectively for a single file rather than entire project. How one can run swiftlint so that it can check only one selected files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run swiftlint with **--path** option, like:

```
swiftlint --path 'path to your file'
```